# Lucene not searching full non-ASCII character

Tags: lucene.net

I am using Lucene seacrh engine for fulltext search it give search result for non ascii character also but the problem is suppose I added a text 帕普部分分配数量 and will search with 
only one character 帕 it will give result but when will search with full non-ascii word  帕普部分分配数量 it is not giving any result, the strange thing is when I put spaces between each charcter for example  帕 普 部 分 分 配 数 量 and theb will search it give result

Will realy appreciate any help

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the same `Analyzer` when indexing and searching.

What happens is your `Analyzer` is indexing each characters as an individual `Term`, and then if you search with a different analyzer (IE `WhiteSpaceAnalyzer`) it searches for a Token containing all the specified characters in your Query.

To search for a sequence of characters like you want, you need to use the same `Analyzer` and have the `QueryParser` build a `PhraseQuery` with all the individual Tokens.

Some sample code of your indexing and searching routines would make it easier to help you.